# for 2 sets, prove this without using venn diagrams or membership tables

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image: prove this:]

How do I prove this without using venn diagrams or membership tables? I don't really understand. can someone help?

I meant, I don't know how to solve it without venn diagrams: I can start with let x belong to (A complement) union B, so x belongs to A complement or x belong to B. So if x belongs to A complement, x doesn't belong to A. So x doesn't belong to A or X belongs to B.. I'm stuck here.

Comment: Can you provide some context for the problem? We don't know what $\mathcal{U}$ or $\overline{A}$ means.

Comment: I gave a hint, but reading again, I have to agree you haven't given enough context here. Is your problem that you don't understand why the result is true (i.e. you *could* prove it "with venn diagrams") or do you understand it but not know how to prove it "without venn diagrams"?

Comment: I meant, I don't know how to solve it without venn diagrams: I can start with let x belong to (A complement) union B, so x belongs to A complement or x belong to B. So if x belongs to A complement, x doesn't belong to A. So x doesn't belong to A or X belongs to B.. I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we will show if $\bar A\cup B = \mathcal U,$ then $A\subseteq B.$ So assume $\bar A\cup B=\mathcal U,$ and let $a\in A.$ Then, in order to show $A\subseteq B$we need to show $a\in B.$ Since $\mathcal U$ is universal, we have $a\in \mathcal U = \bar A \cup B.$ So $a\in \bar A$ or $a\in B.$ Since $a\in A,$ $a\notin \bar A.$ Therefore $a\in B,$ and since $a$ was an arbitrary element of $A,$ this shows that $A\subseteq B.$

Conversely, assume $A\subseteq B.$ In order to show $\bar A\cup B = \mathcal U,$ we will start with and arbitrary $x\in \mathcal U$ and show $x\in \bar A \cup B.$ If $x\notin \bar A,$ then $x\in A,$ and since $A\subseteq B,$ this means $x\in B.$ Thus $x$ is either in $\bar A$ or in $B,$ so $x\in \bar A\cup B.$ Since $x$ was an arbitrary element of $\mathcal U,$ this means $\mathcal U\subseteq \bar A\cup B,$ and since $\mathcal U$ is universal, of course $\bar A\cup B\subseteq \mathcal U,$ so $\bar A \cup B = \mathcal U.$

Answer (score 1):

$A\subset B\Longleftrightarrow A\cup B=B$

$\Longleftrightarrow \overline{A}\cup(A\cup B) = \overline{A}\cup B$

$\Longleftrightarrow (\overline{A}\cup A)\cup B=\overline{A}\cup B$

$\Longleftrightarrow U\cup B=\overline{A}\cup B$

$\Longleftrightarrow U=\overline{A}\cup B$

Hope it helps:)